# Create Profile for External Apps Login licence in Unlocked Package

Tags: community, salesforcedx, scratch-org, licenses, unlocked-package

I created an **Unlocked package** with Community enabled. Because Apex code references it, I need to package a `Profile` for the `External Apps Login` User License.

But I don't see this license in my scratch org. No matter which `edition` I use in my `project-scratch-def.json`.

**How can I make this work?** I checked all the [Scratch Org Definition Configuration Values](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) but couldn't find anything related.

Comment: Can you try with org-shape feature, if it creates scratch org idential to prod/devhub ?